# libgdx problems with make mouse reappear after seconds of inactivity

Tags: java, macos, libgdx, mouse

I have a problem which I have encountered by testing my game, made with LibGDX on my macbook pro laptop (OS X el capitan). I haven't experienced the issue on my windows PC.

**The Problem**

My problem is, that I have made some code, which makes the mouse hiding after 2 seconds of inactivity, and if the mouse is being dragged again, then it should reappear until it is not moved anymore, and then after 2 seconds of inactivity it should hide again. This is working fine when playing on windows PC, but when using my macbook, it is not working properly, because after the mouse has been hidden (after 2 seconds of inactivity), then it won't appear again.

I am using the method `setCursorCatched(true)`, from the [Input](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html) class, to hide the mouse, and the same method again, just with a false input, to make it reappear. To check wether the mouse has been moved relative to its last known position, i am using the methods `getDeltaX()` and `getDeltaY()`. My own method to check inactivity looks like this.

```
/* Time for checking mouse inactivity */
private float lastTimeMouseMoved = 0f;
private float elapsedTimeOfInactivity = 0f;

/**
 * Check for mouse inactivity. If mouse is inactive for XX seconds or more, then hide it.
 * If the mouse is moved show it, and then hide it again after XX seconds of inactivity.
 *
 * @param deltaTime the elapsed time between each frame.
 * @param secondsInactive the time of inactivity in seconds
 */
private void hideMouseAfterInactivity(float deltaTime, float secondsInactive) {
    /* If mouse has been moved */
    if (Gdx.input.getDeltaX() != 0 || Gdx.input.getDeltaY() != 0) {
        /* Show the mouse cursor */
        Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(false);

        /* Keep track of the last known time which the mouse was moved. */
        lastTimeMouseMoved = deltaTime;
        elapsedTimeOfInactivity = lastTimeMouseMoved;
    } else {
        /* check if the time of inactivity is XX seconds or more */
        if (elapsedTimeOfInactivity >= lastTimeMouseMoved + secondsInactive) {
            /* Hide the mouse cursor */
            Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true);
        } else {
            /* update the elapsed time of inactivity */
            elapsedTimeOfInactivity += deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope anyone can tell me what is wrong... I also have a problem with getting the mouse to show, when playing the game in fullscreen after I used the `setCursorCatched(true)`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it isn't the best solution to the problem, it does the job. What I did was to create a 1x1 pixel transparent image, and then instead of using the method `setCursorCatched(boolean catched)` to make the mouse visible and invisble, I have created the following method in my main game class, so I can access it in all my other game screens.

```
//Remember to dispose these on application exit.
private Pixmap normalMouseCursor = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("normal-cursor.png"));
private Pixmap transparentMouseCursor = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("transparent-cursor.png"));

/**
 * Set the mouse cursor to either the normal cursor image or a transparent one if hidden.
 *
 * @param shouldHide true if the mouse should be invisble
 */
public void setMouseCursor(boolean shouldHide) {
    if (shouldHide) {
        Gdx.graphics.setCursor(Gdx.graphics.newCursor(transparentMouseCursor, 0, 0));
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Mouse Cursor is invisible");
    } else {
        Gdx.graphics.setCursor(Gdx.graphics.newCursor(normalMouseCursor, 0, 0));
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Mouse Cursor is visible");
    }
}
```

Only problem here is that the cursor can still click on objects in the game, though it is invisible. A think a solution to this is to make a flag, which is set and used to determine if the mouse cursor is invisible or not.